# How to completely strip HTML tags with newlines after them from string created through CKeditor

Tags: html, string, tags, ckeditor

Here is my code:

```
var htmlString = "<p>ckeditor</p>\n";
```

This is what actually I get when i type "ckeditor" in CKeditor. It automatically appends html tags.

I tried

```
var string = htmlString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

However, what I am getting in **string** is this:

[image]

As you can see above, new line is also appended here, I just want the string with no new line added.
please provide an solution.

Comment: Try `.replace(/<[^>]+>\n*/ig, "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That Really Worked man thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, I posted the suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove any optional amount of newlines you might have after the tag inside the editor, you may add `\n*` after the tag pattern.

Use

```
.replace(/<[^>]+>\n*/g, "")
```

**Details**:

- `<` - a literal `<`
- `[^>]+`  - 1 or more characters other than `>` (since `[^...]` is a *negated* character class)
- `>` - a literal `>`
- `\n*` - **zero or more newline symbols**.